# How to auto-update product category from frontend when using Woocommerce Frontend Manager plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using Woocommerce Frontend Manager Custom Options to update product category/tag via the plugin's Custom Options feature and the following code added to the functions.php (code kindly donated by @Andrew Schultz);

```
add_action('save_post_product', 'update_product_category', 20, 3);

function update_product_category( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
$product = wc_get_product( $post_id );
$delivery_methods = array( 'pick-up', 'postal', 'post', 'parcel' );

$delivery_option = get_post_meta($post_id, 'delivery_option', true);

if( ! empty( $delivery_option ) ) {
    $product_cats = $product->get_category_ids();

    foreach( $delivery_methods as $delivery_method) {
        if( $delivery_option === $delivery_method ) {
            $pickup_cat_id = get_term_by('slug', $delivery_method, 'product_cat')->term_id;

            if( $pickup_cat_id && ! in_array( $pickup_cat_id, $product_cats) ) {
                $product_cats[] = $pickup_cat_id;
                $product->set_category_ids($product_cats);
                $product->save();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

All good when updating from the backend but not when updating or adding new product from the front end. Any insights? @Andrew Schultz Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you are setting the post meta data with that plugin as I am not really familiar with it.  I found an action that fires after the product has been saved to the database which you can hook into to run the same code as I coded before.

```
add_action('wfsm_save_product', 'after_wfsm_save_product', 10, 2);

function after_wfsm_save_product( $post_id, $data ) {
    // insert previous code in here
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew. It didn't work either in the frontend or when hitting update in the backend. I wonder whether it's because of this requirement of the plugin "Important thing is add wfsm-collect-data class to fields (inputs, textareas, selectboxes..) that need to be saved. This way your input values will be available in wfsm_save_product action in an $options array that can be evaluated when saving the product fields. So, make sure your field elements have class="wfsm-collect-data"."

Comment: @BeckPerth if you want my opinion, I wouldn't be using this plugin.  Stick with the official dashboard area for adding products, this product just add overheads with no benefits that I can see.  Better to learn the core WooCommerce actions and filters rather than a 3rd party plugin no one uses.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. You may be right. Plugins seem to open a can of worms. Cheers for all your help.

Comment: @BeckPerth yes I do custom work.  Send me an email with your details, my contact details are in my profile. https://stackoverflow.com/users/2845311/andrew-schultz

Comment: Great! I'm sent you an email.